# fontawesome icons bugged?

Tags: css, font-awesome

This code works with success.I can see a home icon:

```
       <i className="fas fa-home mr-3" /> New York, NY 10012, US
```

However when I try to change the 'home' to another fontawesome icon it bugs:

```
       <i className="fas fa-facebook mr-3" /> New York, NY 10012, US
```

and displays an empty img logo. Here is my html head link

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU"
```

Comment: for facebook it's fab

Comment: If it's still not appearing properly, it might also be because of ad-blockers or tracker-blockers